# не могу подобрать регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, input

не знаю как составить выражение: надо что бы вводились только цифры и каждые 3 символа вставлялся пробел(с начала строки, типа денежного формата, максимум 99 999). составил выражение `replace(/^(\d+)(\d{3})$/g, '$1 $2')` , на http://regexr.com/ , на котором я готовлю выражения, все работает как надо, как только вставляю в js - получается "1 2345"

так выглядит функция

```
$(".s-container").on("change keyup input click", ".input-number", function() {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d+)(\d{3})$/g, '$1 $2');
    });
```

а так сам инпут

```
<input type="text"  tabindex="1" value="0" maxlength="6" class="s-ls input-number rub">
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: применяйте регулярку **только** по событию `change` и все должно заработать

Comment: теперь срабатывает правильно, но только при потере фокуса, а как сделать чтоб на лету срабатывала?

Comment: лучше никак не делать, потому что менять **полностью** значение при инпуте или keyup - весьма плохо для юзера. А так, чтобы просто заработало нужно добавить перед вставкой пробела его удаление. Хотя это всегда лучше вставлять :)

Comment: спасибо, вставка удаления пробела чудом решила проблему. вот и доверяй после этого всяким regexr

Comment: на самом деле `regexr` показывает все правильно, ты же проверял на слове состоящем только из цифр, а здесь после четвертого нажатия цифры в строку добавится пробел и проверь эту новую строку на нем - будет все то же самое

Comment: точно, regexr же не трогает исходную строку. премного благодарен

Comment: @Grundy Ответ-то напишите для формальности.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, да я все собирался, времени не было :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные события *keyup input* срабатывают на каждое отжатие клавиши и изменение значения инпута, поэтому в какой-то момент, после ввода четвертой цифры, происходит замена с добавлением пробела и так как далее цифры вводятся в конец строки - регулярное выражение перестает работать.

Лучше всего не менять полностью значение инпута, это может привести к неочевидным проблемам для пользователя, например если он попытается стрелочками переместить курсор.

Для проблемы в вопросе необходимо просто удалить лишние пробелы, перед тем, как делить число, например так:

```js
$(".s-container").on("change keyup input click", ".input-number", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(' ', '').replace(/^(\d+)(\d{3})$/g, '$1 $2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-container">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" value="0" maxlength="6" class="s-ls input-number rub">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое просто решение и в 2 строчки.

Для целых чисел:

```
var num = 1234567890,
result = num.toLocaleString() ;// result will equal to "1 234 567 890"
```

Для дробных чисел:

```
var num = 1234567.890,
result = num.toLocaleString() + num.toString().slice(num.toString().indexOf('.')) // will equal to 1 234 567.890
```

Вот мой полный ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896761/6932087

Comment: зависит от локали

Comment: Ну можно передавать параметр для пробелов 'ru-RU' для запятых 'en-EN' - удобно.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, с передачей еще не везде поддерживается

Comment: не поддерживается только в safari